# Regex for matching this kind of String in Python 3.x

Tags: python, regex

I have this string,

```
irn
1b6d13bbbe6e0e4bd8e5d7619bf7997672
bc42d1d2442b531a487f9061df2626
```

but sometimes, it will be

```
irn 
1b6d13bbbe6e0e4bd8e5d7619bf7997672bc42d1d2442b531a487f9061df2626
```

, or

```
irn
no
1b6d13bbbe6e0e4bd8e5d7619bf7997672
bc42d1d2442b531a487f9061df2626
```

or

```
irn
no
1b6d13bbbe6e0e4bd8e5d7619bf7997672bc42d1d2442b531a487f9061df2626
```

Actually from apache tika, I am reading the contents of the pdf and getting the output,
so i am using ,

```
re.findall(r'\w+',payload)
```

to pickup all the words and not any other character.

I am using this regex to match the above string ,

```
irn(\s+?)(\w+\s+?)(([a-zA-Z0-9]{64})|([a-zA-Z0-9\s+]{65}))
```

this is working fine for

```
irn
no
1b6d13bbbe6e0e4bd8e5d7619bf7997672
bc42d1d2442b531a487f9061df2626

irn
no
1b6d13bbbe6e0e4bd8e5d7619bf7997672bc42d1d2442b531a487f9061df2626
```

but for this case :

```
irn
1b6d13bbbe6e0e4bd8e5d7619bf7997672
bc42d1d2442b531a487f9061df2626
```

the 2rd group is catching the 2nd line and the group 6 is catching the 3rd line and below subsequent lines till 64 characters.

Since it is not in my hands to maintain the data format in the pdf , can you please help me out here to fix this.

actually, the string will start from "irn", then there may or may not be some words, and then the irn number will be fixed 64 characters long.

Comment: Seems you didn't what you want , is that a string starting with "irn" then 64 hexa char ? or just the hexa ?

Comment: yes, it will be like that only. "irn" , and the 64 alphanumeric number. the thing is , there may be some words followed by irn , do u want me to post the payload which i am getting from apache tika ? but the payload may vary for different pdf's

Comment: apache tika is a pdf content reading library.

Comment: Would this work for you?  [`irn\s*(?:no\s*)?(?:[0-9a-f]\s*){64}`](https://regex101.com/r/4Ewrmx/1)

Comment: The `no` is literally `no`, or could be any string?

Comment: @MarcelPreda , it could be any string. It depends on how people want to display the pdf contents. But it will definitely start with "irn" , we can say "irn" in lower case, cuz I am lowering the overall pdf content to avoid case sensitive issue.

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh , plz give me some time, I will check it right away.

Comment: Hi @GurmanjotSingh, it is working, if there is "no" after irn, but if it is "number" , then it is failing. I have given a upvote to your comment. since it solves a 50% of the problem. Below anubhava 's answer kinda handles all sorts of 2nd word .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional match in 2nd line:

```sh
^irn[\r\n]+(?:(\w+)[\r\n]+)?([a-zA-Z0-9\r\n]{64,65})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HoHoIE/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^irn[\r\n]+`: Match `irn` followed by a 1+ newline characters
- `(?:(\w+)[\r\n]+)?`: Optionally match 1+ word characters followed by 1+ line breaks and capture word in group #1
- `([a-zA-Z0-9\r\n]{64,65})`: Match alphanumerical character or a line feed character 64 or 65 times. Capture this in group #2
- `$`: End

Comment: hi, @anubhava, this works fine, with a small problem , which is solvable. so if there is no word after "irn" , then the 2nd group is capturing the irn , if there is any word after irn, then the 3rd group is capturing the irn. this is fine. Thank you.

Comment: May be you can use: `^irn[\r\n]+(\w+[\r\n]|)([a-zA-Z0-9\r\n]{64,65})$` if you don't mind a line break in group #1

Comment: yes, a line break in the 2nd line is making the regex work fine. Thank you guys.. thank you all..